# Use xpath to find values but exclude certain elements

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm trying to search through an XML file to find matches but I dont want to search every element. The not statement is not working so what am I doing wrong? (have not worked with xpath before)

I want to exclude the elements 'product_image' & 'category_image'

```
$items = $xml->xpath("//item/*[contains(text(), '$find')][not(product_image, category_image)]/parent::*");


<item>
    <id>108</id>
    <title>Big car</title>
    <cat>SUV</cat>
    <color>black</color>
    <product_image>CUa6wVWiHAXHI68mtbUFsNj-F05lDM62_250x250.png</product_image>
    <category_image>comeUYh5I9Juz2hr1NBZCSx9cKSgXXNA_250x250.png</category_image>
</item>
[...]
```

Comment: What is your current / desired output?

Comment: weel it will search through EVERY element and thats not what I am looking for. The NOT part is not working

Comment: How do you want it to work? What is the condition?

Comment: well search through every child of ITEM but not 2 fields(*_image)

Comment: What is `[contains(text(), '$find')]` predicate? What it should do?

Answer (score -1):

Try this XPath to get required output:

```
//item/*[not(self::product_image or self::category_image)]
```

In XPath2.0 it can be

```
//item/*[not(name()=("product_image", "category_image"))]
```

or

```
//item/*[not(ends-with(name(), "_image"))]
```